# C - Recursion with strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion

I am trying to write a function in `C` that gets 2 pointers, one for the first char in a string, and the other to the middle character in the string. The function needs to check if the first half of the string is the same as the second half (ignoring upper and lower case)  and return `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"`.

I don't know what stops the condition for the recursion and why it's not working.

Here is my code. What is the error?

```
#define SIZE 80
enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1 };

int CheckString(char* start, char* middle);

int main()
{
    char str[SIZE], *pstart, *pmiddle;

    printf("Enter a String-->:");
    fgets(str, SIZE, stdin);

    pstart = &str[0];
    pmiddle = &str[(strlen(str) - 1) / 2];

    printf("  %d \n", CheckString(pstart, pmiddle));

    return 0;
}

int CheckString(char* start, char* middle)
{
    if (middle == '\0');
    return TRUE;

    if ((*start == *middle) || (*start == *middle + 32) || (*start == *middle - 32))
        CheckString(start + 1, middle + 1);
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

i changed it to this code

```
int CheckString(char* start, char* middle)
{   
    if ((*start == *middle) || (*start == *middle + 32) || (*start == *middle - 32))
    {
        CheckString(start + 1, middle + 1);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
        return FALSE;
}
```

and now its work but only for the first char and middle its not moving to check the next chars
help someone whats worng ???

Comment: The `pstart` and `pmiddle` variables in the `main` functions are *single characters*, not pointers. Your function will go out of bounds for these variables and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: so change it to `*pstart`?

Comment: This should croak with a compiler warning, since the recursive path does not return a value. You only call `CheckString()`, not return its return value back up the recursion chain. And yes, `pstart` and `pmiddle` need to be pointers to the start and middle of the original string, not copies of the characters at those locations as currently implemented.

Comment: so how do i  return its return value back up the recursion chain?, and i changed pstart to *pstart ..

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-rout‌​e-for-a-dissociation-request)

Answer (score 0):

As said by @some-programmer-dude , `pstart` and `pmiddle` are just character variables which were assigned the value of `str[0]` and `str[(strlen(str) - 1) / 2]` and not their respective addresses. In the function you are passing addresses of `pmid` and `pstart`. You should change the code as follows-

Replace pmid and pstart. Instead change them to pointers -

```
char* pstart,pmid;
pstart = &str[0];
pmiddle = &str[(strlen(str) - 1) / 2];
```

Comment: can you check my code please and tell me whats worng?? @Amarnath Karthi

Answer (score 0):

i think you can still archive this using looping. here is your modified working code. fix issues mention by others.

```
#define SIZE 80
enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1 };

int CheckString(char* start, char* middle);

int main()
{
    char str[SIZE];
    char *pstart = NULL;
    char *pmiddle = NULL;

    printf("Enter a String-->:");
    fgets(str, SIZE, stdin);

    pstart = &str[0];
    pmiddle = &str[(strlen(str) - 1) / 2];

    printf("  %d \n", CheckString(pstart, pmiddle));

    return 0;
}

int CheckString(char* start, char* middle)
{
    int flag = 0;
    char * end = middle;
    while (start != end) {
        if ((*start == *middle) || (*start == *middle + 32) || (*start == *middle - 32))
            flag = 1;
        else
            flag = 0;

      start++; middle++;
    }

        return flag;
}
```

**recursive version**

```
#define SIZE 80
enum { FALSE = 0, TRUE = 1 };

int CheckString(char* start, char* middle, char* end, int []);

int main()
{
    char str[SIZE];
    char *pstart = NULL;
    char *pmiddle = NULL;
    char *end = NULL;
    int  flag[1];
    *flag = 0;

    printf("Enter a String-->:");
    fgets(str, SIZE, stdin);

    pstart = &str[0];
    pmiddle = &str[(strlen(str) - 1) / 2];
    end = pmiddle;
    printf("  %d \n", CheckString(pstart, pmiddle , end, flag));

    return 0;
}

int CheckString(char* start, char* middle, char* end, int *flag)
{

    if (start == end)
        return *flag;

    else 
    {
        if ((*start == *middle) || (*start == *middle + 32) || (*start == *middle - 32))
            *flag = 1;
        else
            *flag = 0;

        start++; middle++;
        return CheckString(start, middle,  end, flag);
    }


}
```

Comment: but why why??????? i know how to do it with loops i asked how to do it with recursion...............RECURSION!!

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga Added recursive version

Answer (score 0):

The other answers point out the main problem, which is the fact that you have to return the value returned by the recursively called function, but there are other problems in your code.

When `fgets` is used to collect the user input, it copies the newline character too and that makes your function fail.

Here is a possible fix, with some other hints:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIZE 160

bool CheckString(char* start, char* middle);

int main()
{
    char str[SIZE];

    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Enter a String-->:");
        if ( fgets(str, SIZE, stdin) == NULL ) break;

        // remove the newline copied in the string by fgets
        size_t length = strcspn(str, "\n");
        str[length] = '\0';

        if ( length == 0 ) continue;

        printf("%s\n", CheckString(str, str + length / 2) ? "True" : "False");
    }

    return 0;
}

bool CheckString(char* start, char* middle)
{
    if ( *middle == '\0') return true; 
    //   ^ note this     ^ here there was a ;

    if ( tolower(*start) == tolower(*middle) )
        return CheckString(start + 1, middle + 1);
    else
        return false;
}
```